# Line spacing problem with \LaTeX{}

Tags: latex, xetex

When I use \LaTeX{} to show the LaTeX logo, the following line of text is pushed down in order to accommodate the subscript 'E' in LaTeX.

How do I override this? Is there an option I can pass to \LaTeX{} ?

EDIT: Problem was due to horizontal space, not vertical space, and was caused by normal text as well as the \LaTeX{} command.

Comment: Add a graphic and/or a minimally reproducible snippet please.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Short answer**: Put \vspace{-0.1cm} after \LaTeX{} (adjust the size of the space to get the effect you want)

**Long answer**: I am not getting this extra spacing you are referring to, but in any case I can show you an example so you see how you can reduce the space between lines. The example of text I am using (I just got the first .tex document I had, so ignore what is written):

> The way the picture is drawn, it
>   implies that the bank doesn't
>   originate loans anymore. Maybe bank
>   are still originators? \LaTeX{} The
>   difference now is that they sell the
>   loans to GSEs and other securitisers
>   and get securities back? Do they also
>   securitise loans?

This is what I get:

[image]

Now using \vspace{-0.1cm}:

> The way the picture is drawn, it
>   implies that the bank doesn't
>   originate loans anymore. Maybe bank
>   are still originators? \LaTeX{} \vspace{-0.1cm} The
>   difference now is that they sell the
>   loans to GSEs and other securitisers
>   and get securities back? Do they also
>   securitise loans?

This is what I get:

[image]

Comment: Ah! I just realised, it wasn't due to the \LaTeX{} itself, it even happened when I added "LaTeX" normally, as normal text.. So it was a problem with horizontal space, not vertical space. But thank you for the detailed response anyway!